# prove $P(A \cap B | C) \geq P(A \cap B | C^c)$ or give counterexample

Tags: probability

A,B,C are events

If $P(A|C) \geq P(A|C^c)$ and $P(B|C) \geq P(B|C^c)$ show that $P(A \cap B | C) \geq P(A \cap B | C^c)$ or give a counterexample

I tried to rearrange the formulars but couldn't find an approach. Tried one counterexample but that didn't work

Is that statement provable or do I have to find a counterexample? If it is provable could you give me an approach please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the extra conditions, one can see that when $A\cap B\subseteq C^c$, the probability on the left is zero while the one on the right is nonzero.

Taking this as a goal, we construct a probability space and events such that the hypothesis conditions hold true as well.

For a specific counterexample, read below:

> Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}, C^c=\{1,2\}, C=\{3,4\}, A=\{1,3\}, B=\{1,4\}$ and a uniform probability distribution over each atom in the space.  I.e. $Pr(X=1)=Pr(X=2)=\dots=\frac{1}{4}$

What is $Pr(A\mid C)$?  $Pr(A\mid C^c)$?  Check the other hypothesis conditions as well.

> $Pr(A\mid C)=Pr(A\mid C^c)=Pr(B\mid C)=Pr(B\mid C^c)=\frac{1}{2}$, so all hypothesis conditions hold.

What is $Pr(A\cap B\mid C)$?  $Pr(A\cap B\mid C^c)$?

> $Pr(A\cap B\mid C) = 0\not\geq Pr(A\cap B\mid C^c)=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

The simplest counterexample I could think of is:

If $C$ then flip two coins.  If $C^c$ then flip one coin and record its result twice.

$A$ if the first coin is heads, $B$ if the second coin is heads.

$P(A|C) = P(A|C^c) = \frac{1}{2}\\ 
P(B|C) = P(B|C^c) = \frac{1}{2}\\
P(A \cap B | C) = \frac{1}{4}\\
P(A \cap B | C^{c}) = \frac{1}{2}$